# PHP match control characters but not whitespace?

Tags: php, regex

Using the POSIX character classes

How to match [:cntrl:] but excluding the [:space:]?

```
$message =  ereg_replace("[[:cntrl:]]", "", $message);
```

Comment: `ereg` functions are deprecated for years

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ereg_* (POSIX) functions have been deprecated for a long time now. You should not contiue using these methods.

According to [POSIX Bracket Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) `[:cntrl:]` resolves to the ASCII range `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` (or the unicode `\p{Cc}`) and `[:space:]` resolves to `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`. Using [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/) to resolve those characters, you are left with an exclusion list of `[\x20\x09-\x0D]`. "Doing the math" you are left with `[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x7F]`. and that leaves you with the following, PHP 5.3 and upward compatible, sanitization:

```
$message = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+/', '', $message);
```

Note that `VT` (Vertical Tab) and `FF` (Form Feed, New page) are also preserved. Depending on your situation you might want to remove these, too:

```
$message = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x7F\x0A\x0C]+/', '', $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[[:cntrl:]]` is basically `[\x00-\x1f\x7F]` and `[[:space:]]` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` [(ref)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes), so the long-hand method would be to use `[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\7F]` (space is 0x20 and out of the cntrl range, `\t\r\n\v\f` are \x09 to \x0D)